# Create directory in remote host using Python

Tags: python, remote-access, remote-server, wmic

I need to create directory in remote host using Python? Can I use `wmic` commands to do that or any suggestions to do this job ?

I am running Python script in Windows pc. I need to create a directory in remote Windows pc. How can I do this?

Comment: the top google search result for "wmic execute command" gives a good hint. You can `wmic /node:[targetIPaddr] /user:[admin] process call create "cmd.exe /c md c:\my\directory"` There is also a `WMI` module that comes with the win32 extensions you can use. You could also open file system objects through wmi but that is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend using ***[Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)***, it's a powerful python tool with a suite of operations for executing local or remote shell commands, as well as auxiliary functionality such as prompting the running user for input, or aborting execution:

1. install fabric :  `pip install fabric`
2. write the following script named **remote_mkdir.py**:

```py
"""
Usage:
    python remote_mkdir.py ip_address username password folder_path
"""

from sys import argv
from fabric.api import run, env


def set_host_config(ip, user, password):
    env.host_string = ip
    env.user = user
    env.password = password

def mkdir(folder_absolute_path):
    """
    creates new folder
    """
    run('mkdir {0}'.format(folder_absolute_path))


def main():
    set_host_config(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])
    mkdir(argv[4]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Usage:**

```
python remote_mkdir.py ip_address username password folder_path
```